# Grafico con porcentaje total por fila con filtro

Tags: powerbi, dax

He generado una columna que me entregue los porcentajes de aprobación según el mes con la siguiente formula

```
Percentage = COUNT(Aprobacion[status])/CALCULATE(COUNT(Aprobacion[status]),ALLEXCEPT(Aprobacion,Aprobacion[Mes]))
```

La variable Status puede tener 3 estados:
-Aprobado
-Rechazado
-Condicional

Lo que deseo es que la formula que escribí arriba excluya a los condicionales.

Ejemplo:
Si en status para Enero tengo 2 Aprobados, 2 rechazados y 1 condicional;

Status   |Percentage enero

Aprobado | 50%

Rechazado| 50%

Answer (score 0):

si es obligatoriamente por fórmula podes hacer lo siguiente:

`Percentage = 
COUNT ( Aprobacion[status] ) / 
CALCULATE ( COUNT ( Aprobacion[status] ), ALLEXCEPT ( Aprobacion, Aprobacion[Mes] ), Aprobacion[status] <> "Condicional" )`

Lo otro que podes hacer es filtrar por objeto visual. Colocas la columna status y filtras por el campo que no queres se tenga en cuenta.

Comment: Hola Agustín! Usé la formula que mencionas pero me sigue dando el mismo resultado, además, si filtro por objeto visual ocurre que los otros dos no suman 100% :c